# Defining and using resources from code and xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to define Colors, Brushes and few others as a system resource and use them later from code and xaml like I have defined strings in AppResources.resx and used them in code like

`MyApp.Resources.AppResources.MyStringResource`

and in xaml like

```
Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=LocalizedResources.MyStringResource}"
```

I came across `ResourceDictionary` at few places while I was looking for a solution to it. But I didn't get to know how and where to add a `ResourceDictionary`

I tried adding it inside App.xaml like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBoundApp1" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF0000" x:Key="ErrorColor"></SolidColorBrush>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

But I don't know how to use it from Code and xaml. Also are there any other ways or places where I can add a `ResourceDictionary` or any other thing to be used again and again later.

Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across lots of solutions when am trying to achieve this and finally got the best solution. Just follow below steps.

First create a folder called **Themes** inside your project and add an class file in it. Name the class file called **Generic.xaml**, replace the existing C# code and add the following files in to it.

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">    
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF0000" x:Key="ErrorColor"></SolidColorBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And rebuild the project. Then add the following lines of code inside App.xaml.

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Finally apply the style wherever you want in your project like this,

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello" Foreground="{StaticResource ErrorColor}"/>
```

Add the styles you want in **Generic.xaml** and call those styles in your project.

Comment: This is kinda solution I was looking for. But it gives this error. `Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source'.` in App.xaml where I am adding MergedDictionaries

Comment: Try adding /YourProjectName;component/Themes/Generic.xaml inside source in ResourceDictionary in App.xaml.

Comment: Cool. It worked. But can you please explain why it worked now and why not earlier. I have seen at many places where Source is simply defined as `Source="/Themes/Generic.xaml"`. So why was it not working for my case

Comment: There is a bug on not being able to use relative URIs for the Source in generic.xaml (31783) directly in your code. In that case, the non-relative form should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solidColorBrush in xaml like so:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource ErrorColor}">
</Border>
```

[See link for more details on using Application Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746624(v=vs.110).aspx)

[See here for a more in depth look at Xaml resources in general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT**

In code behind, although I wouldn't advise this as there is more room for error you would do:

```
SolidColorBrush = this.FindResource("ErrorColor") as SolidColorBrush;
```

Comment: Okay. But how can I use it in Code?

Comment: see edit to see how to use Xaml resources in code behind

Comment: `FindResource` or `TryFindResource` are not available for Windows Phone.

Comment: I got the solution for code. I have used it like this `App.Current.Resources["ErrorColor"]`. But thanks for the help.