# Declare storyboard in resources and calling it everywhere

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, storyboard

I have a storyboard animation which i declared in resources. Now how to call that storyboard throughout the application?

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="Splash">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.8" To="-882" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="splash" d:IsOptimized="True">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <SineEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
```

I have gone through some solutions but they are using **FindResource** to get the storyboard but its not available in Windows Phone. How to call this storyboard?

Comment: In resources of what? is it in resources of page and you want to call it from the same page?

Comment: No, I want to call that storyboard in about 3 pages. I have created a separate resource file as said in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889896/defining-and-using-resources-from-code-and-xaml/24902255#24902255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your `Storyboard` inside the `PhoneApplicationPage.Resources` tag, change `x:Name` to `x:Key` then in code behind create a property like this:

```
public Storyboard SplashStoryboard
{
    get
    {
        return (Storyboard)Resources["Splash"] ?? new Storyboard(); 
        //return a new Storyboard to avoid NullReferenceException;
    }
}
```

then use it wherever you want:

```
SplashStoryboard.Begin(); //or other methods
```

If you put your Storyboard inside `App.Resources` even from an external file through `MergedDictionaries` example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889896/defining-and-using-resources-from-code-and-xaml/24902255#24902255)
You must change your property like this:

```
public Storyboard SplashStoryboard
{
    get
    {
        return (Storyboard)App.Current.Resources["Splash"] ?? new Storyboard(); 
        //return a new Storyboard to avoid NullReferenceException;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great that works!! Thanks for the help. But I want that to be declared in Resource file so that I can share it anywhere? How about that?

Comment: You can do it in App.xaml

Comment: I have declared the resource file as said in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889896/defining-and-using-resources-from-code-and-xaml/24902255#24902255 Cant I declare in that generic.xaml file?

Comment: The only issue is the TargetName that you must set it in every view before calling Begin()

Comment: You can declare it in a generic.xaml file

Comment: But how? If I declare that storyboard in Generic.xaml, storyboard not working.

Comment: After that you must change the way you get it from the Resources

Comment: replace `Resources` in the return statement with this `App.Current.Resources`

Comment: Getting InvalidOperationException on button click. Any other way?

Comment: I didn't get the answer for my solution yet.